# morse code decoder - determine end of message

Tags: arduino, morse-code

I'm building a morse code decoder.

One of the problems which I ran into was: how do you know when the message ends? Suppose a character is transmitted then you get seven dots of silence - you might assume this to be a space but equally could it not be the end of the message? Are you supposed to rely upon end of message prosigns?

Or alternatively if you get another 7 dots of silence is this another space? I've looked all over for guidance on this but cannot find any.

Answer (score 1):

End of work is `▄  ▄  ▄  ▄▄▄  ▄  ▄▄▄`

`+` is use for *End of transmission, you turn*: `▄  ▄▄▄  ▄  ▄▄▄  ▄`

Other command can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code